# Which Power Management Topology

Tags: power, high-voltage, boost, power-management

This is a bit of an open question but I am seeking advice on further research and also some search terms so I can find the best solution.

The project requires a 48V source from a battery pack which needs to be boosted to 600V-800VDC (allowing a smaller CSA cable to be used), this will then be stepped down again to a more useable voltage for a load with a 500W power requirement.

I would ideally like to use a dedicated management IC but cannot find anything that meets the voltage/power requirements, so looking for advice on what SMPS or power conversion topologies to investigate further.

Comment: why step up and then down? And: can your 18V source 500W at all? You'll probably want to describe your application in way more detail to get sensible answers!

Comment: Asking about a mystery load always makes things harder...

Comment: The step-up and step-down is so a smaller CSA of cable can be used in the application

Comment: 500W is too much for a flyback, I'd look into a phase-shifted full-bridge or maybe even an LLC.  If you just need to boost the voltage to keep the cable diameter down you might do an unregulated resonant converter into a step-up transformer and let the other end handle the regulation.

Comment: John D thanks for the comment I was looking at flyback and push pull as it allows greater power, a full bridge LLC seems like a good option, complex but worth researching further.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a 'use an IC' type of problem. You're asking for a 500W high-voltage inverter, which is a board- or box-level solution that involves safety type approvals.

In this case, if this is your first foray into the market, please consider an off-the shelf inverter / step-down pair from a reputable vendor like Schneider, Alpha, etc.

I also suggest that you use AC. This has some implications for safety, especially breakers and the possibility of using galvanic isolation for your hardware.